# Do Files Written In .NET Exist After The Debugging Stops (Storing Images)?

Tags: c#, file, .net-core, userform

I am doing a project in .NET and I would like to store new images provided by the user through a form, e.g. profile pictures or images of news articles and so on. I thought about writing them to the wwwroot folder, controller having caught the form, and then storing its link in the appropriate spot in the database.

Would that work, or would the user's files/images get deleted after the application ends?

Comment: In short, yes, anything saved to the filesystem is independient of program restarts, unless you explicitly delete it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simple enough to try it and see? `File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\test.txt", "testing");`  Downvote for lack of research effort.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us in order for us to help you; please research first.

Comment: But, when retrieving your images, be forewarned that your combined DB + filesystem write will not be transactional (unless you use a transactional write and enlist the filesystem into the transaction (which I've never seen anyone do)).  Your code just needs to be ready for slightly inconsistent data

Answer (score 1):

Files written by your application will naturally remain where they are, unless explicitly deleted (or unless you're running in e.g. a container with ephemeral storage).

Storing user media on disk (or in the cloud), and a reference in the database is standard procedure.

Comment: I would also add that saving user content in the same place as your apps files is probably not a good idea. This may complicate releasing updates or scaling your application